# Changing meta tag through iframe

Tags: php, jquery, html

There's a need to change meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

**from text/html to text/plain** of external website accessed on personal domain through iframe.

Code:

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>


  <style type="text/css">

   html, body, div, iframe { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
   iframe { display:block; width:100%; border:none; }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>

  <div>
   <iframe src="http://other-domain-website.com">
       </iframe>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to change more then this you can try to get this website as a text. Parse it, change tag then insert as iframe with src="mydomain/parse.php".

Or more simple way, you can use JQuery:

```
$("#iframe").contents().find('meta[http-equiv="Content-Type"]').attr('content', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

More info in documentation: http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: @Radoslow Halicki This option doesn't seem to work. Can you elaborate more on parse option?

Comment: Have you added id to iframe? $("#your_iframe_id").